# Need to fetch the max value in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having the below cypher query which gets two values, out of which I need to fetch the max value. Is it possible?

```
with ['get','all','Movie','The Matrix'] as toks unwind toks as tok 
match (a) where any(x in labels(a) where x=tok)
return a ,1 as rank UNION
with ['get','all','Movie','The Matrix'] as toks unwind toks as tok 
match (a) where a.title =tok
return a,2 as rank
```

I am not able to attach screenshot, so just pasting the query am running and the output am getting from it:

```
WITH ['get','all','Movie','The Matrix'] AS toks UNWIND toks as tok 
MATCH (a)WHERE ANY(x IN LABELS(a) WHERE x=tok) 
OR a.title = tok RETURN DISTINCT (a), 
    CASE WHEN a.title = tok THEN 2
    ELSE 1 END as rank
```

Response:

- {"title":"Charlie Wilson's War","released":2007,"tagline":"A stiff
  drink. A little mascara. A lot of nerve. Who said they couldn't bring
  down the Soviet empire."}    **1**
- {"title":"The Polar
  Express","released":2004,"tagline":"This Holiday Seasonâ€¦
  Believe"}    1 {"title":"A League of Their
  Own","released":1992,"tagline":"Once in a lifetime you get a chance
  to do something different."} **1**
- {"title":"The
  Matrix","released":1999,"tagline":"Welcome to the Real World"}   **2**

Here 1,1,2 are the ranks being returned. I need only the maximum of the Ranks being returned. In my case, it should return only one row as

```
  {"title":"The
   Matrix","released":1999,"tagline":"Welcome to the Real World"}   **2**
```

Comment: See my update which uses `Order By` and `Limit` to reduce number of returned records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to achieve this using a case statement.

```
WITH ['get','all','Movie','The Matrix'] AS toks UNWIND toks as tok 
MATCH (a)
WHERE ANY(x IN LABELS(a) WHERE x=tok) 
OR a.title = tok
RETURN DISTINCT (a), 
    CASE WHEN a.title = tok THEN 2
    ELSE 1 END as rank
```

This has the advantage of not running the UNWIND twice. It is important to note the case ordering for any results that might have a label match and a title match. In the example I have given a match on label and title will still return `2` as the rank as the case statement will return on the first matched case.

**Edit**

Not understanding exactly what you want to achieve, but understanding that my current iteration does not actually work (the DISTINCT returns distinct rows not values), I have quickly made a very simple console example which you can see [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=v7223y):

```
WITH ['get', 'all', 'Movie', 'The Matrix'] AS toks
MATCH (a)
WHERE ANY (x IN LABELS(a) 
       WHERE x IN toks) OR a.title IN toks
RETURN a AS thing,CASE
WHEN a.title IN toks
THEN 2
ELSE 1 END AS rank
ORDER BY rank DESC , thing.title ASC
```

The case statement preferentially treats the title, giving it a rank of 2, and I have taken 2 to be a greater rank than 1 when sorting.

**Edit 2**
If you only want to get the top result then using the sort I've added above (with or without the title element, limit the query to a single result (you can play with this in the console).

```
WITH ['get', 'all', 'Movie', 'The Matrix'] AS toks
MATCH (a)
WHERE ANY (x IN LABELS(a) 
       WHERE x IN toks) OR a.title IN toks
RETURN a AS thing,CASE
WHEN a.title IN toks
THEN 2
ELSE 1 END AS rank
ORDER BY rank DESC , thing.title ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The query is fine but how can I return the maximum of the rank?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand your question. The case statement will only return a single value as `rank`, match which ever case you find more important first, and that will be your returned value. Do you mean the maximum of 1 and 2, and is 1 the maximum (as you might assume by `rank`) or 2 the maximum (as in maximum value)?

Comment: I am using the same query.. but it is returning me the results with rank 1 and Rank 2 as well.. ill attach the screenshots with my question